# Unreasonable closure of question

Tags: discussion

Q: [TERM value for Windows 10 terminal](https://superuser.com/questions/1691010/term-value-for-windows-10-terminal)

Who closed this question? How is this question not clear? It looks to me whoever closed this should not have the power to close questions because he is incompetent.

Answer (score 6):

#### Who closed this question?

The question was closed as needing details or clarity by 5 members of the community who have earned the close vote privilege.

Note:

Your question has been reopened and closed as a duplicate of [TERM system environment variable not set - Windows 10 - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1690372/term-system-environment-variable-not-set-windows-10)

#### It looks to me whoever closed this should not have the power to close questions because he is incompetent.

Please read our [Code of Conduct](https://superuser.com/conduct):

> No name-calling or personal attacks.

Calling a user (or group of users) "incompetent" is not allowed.